# PHP - Image with no margin

Tags: css, margin

https://i.stack.imgur.com/APVxF.jpg

I want to remove the margins from the top and left off the picture. What i have to
write inside my status.php file?

Comment: Never ever do the styling directly in PHP!

Comment: i know, but what my php does it to produce a red image if server offline, and green if server online, and since i dont know anything about php programing i needed an easy way out,

Comment: Still you should only give a class to HTML element generated by PHP and style for the class should be defined in CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes to margins etc should really be done via a css file or placed into `<style>` tags.

ie place this at the top of the page

```
<style>
img {margin:0; padding:0;}
</style>
```

Alternatively you can add an inline style rule. From the information given you will need to do something like this:

```
echo '<img src="imgurl" alt="Alt Text" style="margin:0; padding:0;" />'
```

The likelihood is that this is margin, though could potentially be padding, hence why I have added both rules. You should should use chrome inspect or similar to confirm if it is margin or padding. This will also tell you if it is specifically the image that has margin/padding or another element.

Comment: @user3211668 that would suggest the margin is not on the image but another element, see this link for chrome inspector http://support.goodlayers.com/how-to-use-google-chrome-inspect-element-tool/. I literally could not live without this tool.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to define the following CSS in your page:

```
html, body {margin: 0;}
```

Although `body` should be enough

Comment: thank you for the fat reply. i already knew that, but i couldnt adapt it inside php (im php newbie). I tried the answer below and it worked. Im sure yours would work aswell but i dont have any css or html file, only php.